# How to handle dependency cycle in commonjs

Tags: javascript, commonjs, extendscript

I've been working on a commonjs implementation on ExtendScript Toolkit lately and I am stuck with this "dependency cycle" thing. My code passed most of the commonjs compliance tests except on these: cyclic, determinism, exactExports, monkeys.

The wiki states that:

> If there is a dependency cycle, the foreign module may not have finished executing at the time it is required by one of its transitive dependencies; in this case, the object returned by "require" must contain at least the exports that the foreign module has prepared before the call to require that led to the current module's execution.

Can somebody please explain to me further how this specification should be implemented? Do I throw an exception if it detects a dependency cycle?

You can check my code at: https://github.com/madevelopers/estk

Only tested on ExtendScript Toolkit CS6

Answer (score 4):

In CommonJS, you attach the things you're exporting onto an export object.  The intention of the spec is that if there is a 'require' statement part way through a file and then part way through that required file there is a require of the original file, then the second require gets the state of the exports object as it is at that point.  I'll provide an example.

```
// file A.js

exports.A1 = {};
exports.A2 = {};

// The object returned from this require call has B1, B2 and B3
var B = require('./B.js'); 
exports.A3 = B.B1;
```

And in file B.js:

```
// fie B.js

exports.B1 = {};
exports.B2 = {};

// This require call causes a cycle. The object returned has only A1 and A2.
// A3 will be added to the exports object later, *after* this file is loaded.
var A = require('./A.js');
exports.B3 = A.A1;
```

This example would have worked correctly, even though there is a cycle in the code.  Here's another example that would work even though it is circular:

```
var OtherModule = require('./OtherModule.js');

// even if OtherModule requires this file and causes a circular dependency
// this will work, since doAThing is only defined and not called by requiring this
// this file.  By the time doAThing is called, OtherModule will have finished
// loading.

exports.doAThing = function() {
    return OtherModule.doSomething() + 3;
}
```

Even though OtherModule.doSomething doesn't exist when this files code is executed and doAThing is defined, as long as doAThing doesn't get called until later, then everything is fine.

Comment: But when does each file stops requiring each other? On your first example `a` requires `b` then `b` requires `a` it's a clear cycle. How do I trap this from not going infinite?

Comment: When you require something for a second time, you get the exact same object that you got the first time it was required.  In this case `a` has already been required, so it is not run again. The fact that it is part of a cycle simply means that the object you get back from `require('./a.js')` is not the completed `A` object, that is, it is missing any properties that get added after the require that causes the cycle.   You could have a look at https://github.com/kybernetikos/browser-modules/blob/gh-pages/browser-modules.js to see what I mean.